# Is there a shorter way to write this python code? (without repeat the try/except statments for example)

Tags: python

```
while True:
    hh=input('enter hours: ')
    if hh == 'done':
        break
    try:
        h=float(hh)
    except:
        print('please enter numeric input!')
        continue
    rr=input('enter rate: ')
    if rr == 'done':
        break
    try:
        r=float(rr)
    except:
        print('please enter a numeric input!')
        continue
    if h<=40:
        p=h*r
    else:
        x=h-40
        xr=r*1.5
        p=40*r+x*xr
    print(p)
print('thank you for using this code')
```

Comment: Turn the relevant section of the code into a function.

Comment: You know if you enter an invalid value for the second input, it takes you back to the first input? is that intentional?

Comment: Look for the common sections of your code and  create a function from that.   Feed in anything that is custom like the prompt string and return the collected value, etc.